# attached 'property was already registered by' my generic BaseAttachedProperty class causes design time exception

Tags: wpf, vb.net, generics, exception, design-time

I'm developing an engineering application for work in WPF with VB.net and have a base class for attached properties which is based on [Angel Six's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trR5RQGEteM) code in C#.  My base attached property is working fine at run time as the application executes without any problems, but for some reason the Visual Studio 2017 design time has suddenly started throwing exceptions on all of my attached properties giving the error, 'Value' property is already registered by 'BaseAttachedProperty'2_1_190297300'. This makes designing any further UI rather challenging.

My problems started when I introduced a dependency object on a custom user control which would fire off an update event whenever it was updated and then manually update the data context of the custom control. This allowed the custom control to update the main page in which it was created.

I've since deleted the custom user control and the dependency object, but the problem still remains.  I've then closed my solution, closed Visual Studio, deleted the bin and obj folders and restarted, but the problem persists.

I've searched the internet and stack overflow extensively for the last few days, but haven't been able to find a solution, which is unusual because up to until now I've always been able to solve any problems I've had by google searching.  While the 'property is already registered by' error seems to be a common one, the solution to the problems associated with this error seems to be different in all cases.

This is my base attached property with the standard get/set value code removed, along with the overridable event methods...

```vb
Public MustInherit Class BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent As {BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]), New}, [Property])

    Private Shared defaultVal As [Property] = Nothing

#Region "Public Events"


#End Region

#Region "Public Properties"

    Public Shared Property Instance As Parent = New Parent()

#End Region

#Region "Attached Property Definitions"

    Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Value",
        GetType([Property]),
        GetType(BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property])),
        New UIPropertyMetadata(defaultVal,
                               New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnValuePropertyChanged),
                               New CoerceValueCallback(AddressOf OnValuePropertyUpdated)))


    Private Shared Sub OnValuePropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)

        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.OnValueChanged(d, e)

        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.ValueChanged(d, e)

    End Sub

    Private Shared Function OnValuePropertyUpdated(d As DependencyObject, value As Object) As Object

        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.OnValueUpdated(d, value)

        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.ValueUpdated(d, value)

        Return value

    End Function
```

The code for an attached property which then does no more than pass a static value is then as follows...

```vb
Public Class ControlTitleProperty
    Inherits BaseAttachedProperty(Of ControlTitleProperty, String)

End Class
```

The attached properties are then called in xaml as you would expect...

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding PhasePageViewModel.ViscosityValue, 
                                                    Source={x:Static local:ViewModelLocator.Instance},
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     Style="{StaticResource ValueAndUnitsBox}"
                                     local:NumericInputProperty.Value="True"
                                     local:ControlTitleProperty.Value="Viscosity"
                                     local:ControlDescriptionProperty.Value="The viscosity of this phase and the associated units"/>
```

Since I'm using the attached properties in most of my resource dictionaries, the design time isn't working properly anywhere in my project, so I'd really appreciate some help fixing it.  I've been scratching my head for the last few days with it, but to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand VB, but surely you can't use inheritance with attached properties, since the DependencyProperty identifier field declaration and the Get/Set methods are all static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching and help from Phil to make sure that my base attached property class was as close as possible to the original C# code I ended up gradually re-building my user interface in a new project piece by piece, starting with the attached properties. After adding each class to the new project as an existing item from the old project I would clean and build the project to see if that broke the Visual Studio designer.  To my surprise, none of my code managed to break the designer and what I ended up with was a carbon copy of my old project but now with the designer in Visual Studio working again.

I can only surmise that when I introduced my custom dependency property for the data context of my custom control, I managed to break the designer in a way that couldn't be undone by simply deleting the offending code and then re-building. [This](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2017/03/13/how-to-debug-the-xaml-designer/) blog post by Travis Illig alludes to a "shadow cache" that is used by the designer to render the design time appearance of your UI within Visual Studio.  I believe that this is what I managed to break.

It's taken me a number of painstaking days to rebuild my project, days that I could have saved if I'd have had a recent back up of my project.  So just in case this problem pops up again in the future, I'm going to back my project up on a regular basis!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your class is based on a C# class something like the one here:

https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/306/fasetto-word/Source/Fasetto.Word/AttachedProperties/BaseAttachedProperty.cs/#

In your code, the two functions OnValuePropertyChanged and OnValuePropertyUpdated call the method ValueUpdated.

```
Private Shared Sub OnValuePropertyChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.OnValueChanged(d, e)
    TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.ValueChanged(d, e)
End Sub

Private Shared Function OnValuePropertyUpdated(d As DependencyObject, value As Object) As Object
    TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.OnValueUpdated(d, value)
    TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.ValueUpdated(d, value)
    Return value
End Function
```

If I'm right about the original C# code, then ValueUpdated is actually an event not a method.

In VB.NET you cannot raise an event with this syntax, you have to use a RaiseEvent statement.

I don't think that there is any direct way to raise an event from a static method in VB.NET.  I would recommend defining a non static member and calling it via the instance pointer.

```
Private Shared Sub OnValuePropertyChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.OnValueChanged(d, e)
    TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.FireValueChanged(d, e)
End Sub

Private Sub FireValueChanged ( d As DependencyObject, value As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs )
  RaiseEvent ValueUpdated ( d, value )
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could raise the event from the OnValueChanged method.

This is the complete class which I generated by converting the C# code automatically and then fixed the compilation errors.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows

Public MustInherit Class BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent As New, [Property])

    Public Event ValueChanged As Action(Of DependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Public Event ValueUpdated As Action(Of DependencyObject, Object)

    Public Shared Property Instance As Parent = New Parent()

    Private Shared defValue As [Property] = Nothing

    Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty _
                      = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ( "Value", _
                                                              GetType([Property]), _
                                                              GetType(BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property])), _
                                                              New UIPropertyMetadata ( defValue, _
                                                                                       New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnValuePropertyChanged), _
                                                                                       New CoerceValueCallback(AddressOf OnValuePropertyUpdated)) )

    Public Property Value as [Property]

    Private Shared Sub OnValuePropertyChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.OnValueChanged(d, e)
        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.FireValueChanged(d, e)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function OnValuePropertyUpdated(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal value As Object) As Object
        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.OnValueUpdated(d, value)
        TryCast(Instance, BaseAttachedProperty(Of Parent, [Property]))?.FireValueUpdated(d, value)
        Return value
    End Function

    Private Sub FireValueChanged ( d As DependencyObject, value As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs )
      RaiseEvent ValueChanged ( d, value )
    End Sub

    Private Sub FireValueUpdated ( d As DependencyObject, value As [Property] )
      RaiseEvent ValueUpdated ( d, value )
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetValue(ByVal d As DependencyObject) As [Property]
        Return CType(d.GetValue(ValueProperty), [Property])
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetValue(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal value As [Property])
        d.SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub OnValueChanged(ByVal sender As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub OnValueUpdated(ByVal sender As DependencyObject, ByVal value As Object)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have tested this code using three attribute definitions

```
Public Class ControlDescriptionProperty
 Inherits BaseAttachedProperty(Of ControlDescriptionProperty, String)

End Class

Public Class ControlTitleProperty
 Inherits BaseAttachedProperty(Of ControlTitleProperty, String)

End Class

Public Class NumericInputProperty
 Inherits BaseAttachedProperty(Of NumericInputProperty, Boolean)

End Class
```

With the following XAML code it does not generate an error at run time or in the designer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Phil. My original code did compile and run fine, although I must admit that the in ability to raise and event from a shared method in VB.net did confuse me when I was converting from the fasetto c# code.

Comment: I've implemented your version of the code and it compiles fine, but then get an 'InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.'' in the OnValuePropertyUpdated function when it tries to execute the FireValueChanged method.  I'm not sure what cast it's referring to because I tried changing the line to Instance.FireValueChanged(d, value) and still got the same error.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited the code to define two separate methods FireValueChanged and FireValueUpdated, with different parameter types.

Comment: By the way, the automatic code conversion from C# to VB.NET replaced "default(Property)" with "Nothing". I don't think there is any equivalent of the C# keyword "default" in VB.NET so this might be the best conversion. However, i don't think this will work with Value types (e.g. bool, or integer). I converted the code using [the Telerik converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).

Comment: Thanks Phil. That has sorted out the run time error. When I used 'Nothing' as the default value in the UIPropertyMetadata object it gives an argument exception at run time 'Default value type does not match type of property 'value''. So I created the 'defaultVal' private member as type of Parent and set that to Nothing and it seemed to accept that at run time.

Comment: I prefer your implementation of the BaseAttachedProperty class to my original one as this is closer to the original C# code. Unfortunately, it still hasn't fixed the issue I'm having with the design time in Visual Studio. After updating the base attached property class I tried closing Visual Studio, deleting the bin and obj folders re-opening and doing a clean and build, but this didn't help.  So although you've been very helpful, I'm not able to mark my query as answered yet.

Comment: I have made another update to the class, which is to add a Shared variable defValue and to specify it as a parameter to UIPropertyMetadata. I think that must be very similar to the change you described. I am not getting an error in the designer, as you can see from the screen shot which I have added.